# I only want to get a hard disk path from Java

Tags: java, file, disk

I only want to get a path from Java that is a hard disk, not a network disk or usb.
I used FileSystemView but it wasn't useful.
How can I get disk list?
ex) I have C drive, D drive, H USB, but I only want to get C and D

```
File[] drives = File.listRoots();
if (drives != null && drives.length > 0) {
    for (File aDrive : drives) {                                        
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
        String driveType = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(aDrive);
        if(fsv.isFileSystemRoot(aDrive)) {
            System.out.println("aDrive => " + aDrive + " : driveType => " + driveType + " ***");
        } else {
            System.out.println("aDrive => " + aDrive + " : driveType => " + driveType);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
for (FileStore fs: FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
  if (fs.type().equals("NTFS")) {
     System.out.println(fs);
   }
}
```